# How to update joined table using condition

Tags: postgresql

I'm having an issue with a simple update statement. I'm new to postgresql and I'm still stuck on MS Sql Server syntax.
What I want to do is to update all records from table1 which are not present / don't exist in table2.  Table1 and Table2 are having an 1 to 1 relation. The join column is "colx" from my example

On Ms SQL Server I would have something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 set col1='some value' from table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.colx=t2.colx WHERE t2.colx IS NULL
```

or

```
UPDATE table1 set col1='some value' from table1 t1 where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.colx=t2.colx)
```

My issue is when performing the same on PostgreSql it updates all records from table1, not only the records matching the condition (e.g. I was expecting 4 records to be updated, but all records from table1 are updated instead).
I checked using a select statement the join condition for all possible approaches and I have the expected result (e.g. 4 records).

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output with problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear about the requirement.
What I understood is you want to update the value of `col1` in `table1` for those records which are not present in the `table2`.

You can try it this way in `Postgresql`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 set col1='some value' where not exists(select 1 from table2 where colx=t1.colx)
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c500d083845fd9c4760fe80ec3765769)

Comment: i've updated the initial thread. I'm trying to perform an update statement on missing records using a join column

Comment: the answer provided is the same as I've used in my example (e.g. version 2) and it doesn't work. It updates all records from table1! Not just the records from table1 which are not present in table2

Comment: Nope both queries are different please check once. your's will update all records because you are referring` table1` 2 times in your query due to that it is updating with one instance and comparing with one instance. I have added fiddle for your reference